# Is it permitted to use the ocean as a mikvah during the nine days?

Tags: mikvah-ritual-bath, nine-days

Is one permitted to use the ocean as a mikvah during the nine days, or does the prohibition against swimming make it not-permitted?

Comment: Why would the ocean be any different than a regular *Mikvah*?

Comment: source for not swimming during the nine days please?

Comment: @Bach SA OC 551:16 is probably what he's referring to.

Comment: @ploni more likely 551:18

Comment: @DoubleAA What's the connection between being alone and swimming?

Comment: Man or woman who is purifying for *Niddah*? There may be a difference in ruling.

Comment: @Ploni the only difference between an ocean and a mikva is the former is more dangerous. since your citation clearly excludes tzorekh mitzva, he must be referring to the issue of danger during that time period.