# Can a lake or river be used as a kosher Mikva?

Tags: halacha, mikvah-ritual-bath

My question is regarding the mikvah. Can a river or lake (like somewhere out in the forest or wilderness or wherever) be used as a mikvah? I know and have heard of many pious and holy Jews (even many great Kabbalists and Hasidic masters) throughout history (and indeed, even in the Bible) using natural bodies of water such as oceans, lakes and rivers as a mikvah when needed and for ritual purity. So, if I’m outside walking somewhere in the forest for example, and I require the use of a mikvah, and by chance encounter I come upon a river or a little lake... can I use it as a mikvah? My question is more concerning the use of a mikvah for men than for women. I’d also appreciate some information about some of the kabbalistic aspects and customs regarding the mikvah. Thank you very much.

Comment: The ocean is as kosher a mikvah as you can find. Also most lakes. Springs, as long as they contain enough water, are perfect mikvaot. Rivers can be problematic as they must be fed by groundwater rather than rainfall, but if you find one fed mostly by groundwater, it's certainly kosher. Here's a link to some info:https://www.yoatzot.org/questions-and-answers/856/

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/119567/15256 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/84427/15256 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17576/15256

Comment: Just a comment as I don't have any specific sources at the moment. I know I heard at least once a Rabbi give a long discussion of this. Bottom line was that for a river/stream it depends on the source, which led to an argument among the locals as to when, based on recent rainfall, a particular local stream would be valid or not. End result: Ask your LOR *and* ask your local hydrologist.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is - Yes, it is allowed (although I would advise discussing it with your LOR).

With regards to rivers though, it is not clear-cut, the Shulchan Aruch in [Yoreh Deah 201:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.201.2?lang=bi) indicates that there is a machlokes (dispute) which is dependent on the nature of the body of water. The Rema provides a meikel (lenient) approach:

> מי מעיין מטהרין אף בזוחלין (פירוש זוחלין נמשכים והולכים ואינן מכונסים) מי גשמים אין מטהרין אלא באשבורן (פירוש מקום עמוק שמתכנסים בו המים ונקרא אשבורן) (אבל על ידי זחילה פסולין מן התורה (ב"י בשם מהרי"ק שורש קט"ו ות"ה סימן רכ"ד) אם הם לחוד בלא מעיין) היו הזוחלין מן המעיין מתערבי' עם הנוטפי' שהם מי גשמים הרי הכל כמעיין לכל דבר ואם רבו הנוטפים על הזוחלין וכן אם רבו מי גשמים על מי הנהר אינם מטהרים בזוחלין אלא באשבורן לפיכך צריך להקיף מפץ (פי' כעין מחצלת) וכיוצא בו באותו הנהר המעורב עד שיקוו המים ויטבול בהם: הגה וכן נכון להורות ולהחמיר (מהרי"ק ות"ה שם ושאר אחרוני' כתבו ויש להחמיר כשטת הר"ם ורא"ש וסייעתם) **אבל יש מתירים לטבול בנהרות כל השנה אף בשעת הגשמים והפשרת שלגים ורבו הנוטפים על הזוחלין משום דעיקר גידול הנהר הוא ממקום מקורו (טור בשם ר"ת וב"י בשם רש"י וסה"ת וסמ"ג) וכן נהגו ברוב המקומות במקום שאין מקוה ואין למחות ביד הנוהגין להקל כי יש להם על מי שיסמוכו (מהרי"ק ובת"ה שם ומהרי"ו סימן ע' וב"ז סימן קנ"ד) מיהו יש ליזהר מלטבול בנהר המתהוה לגמרי ע"י גשמים וכשאין גשמים פוסק לגמרי** אף על פי ששאר נהרות שופכים לתוכו בשעת הגשמים ומתהוה על ידן מ"מ הואיל ופוסק לגמרי בשעה שאין גשמים אסור לטבול בו דרך זחילתו עד שיקוו המים שבתוכו (שם במהרי"ק) אבל בנהר שאינו פוסק אע"פ שבשעת הגשמים מתרחב ומתפשט על כל גדותיו מותר לטבול בו בכל מקום (ב"י לדעת המרדכי והאשיר"י והתוספ') לפי סברת המקילין ולפי מה שנהגו
>
> Spring water purifies even when it is flowing. Rain water only purifies when in a still body, but when it is flowing, it is Biblically invalid, if it is detached from a spring. If the flowing water from a spring mixed with downflow which derives from rain, then the whole mixture has the status of the spring for all purposes. But if the downflow is greater than the spring flow, or similarly if rain water makes up the majority of the water in a river, they do not purify while flowing but only while still. Therefore one must set up a barrier or something like it in the mixed river, until the water gathers together and one can immerse in it. [Comment of Rema: And thus it is correct to teach and to be stringent. **But some permit immersion in rivers all year round, even during rain and snowmelt season, when the downflow is greater than the spring flow, because the essence of the river's size is from its source location. This is the practice in most places where there is no mikveh, and we should not reprimand those who have the custom to be lenient, because they have authorities to rely on. However, one must be careful not to immerse in a river that appears entirely through rain, and when there is no rain it stops completely.** Even if other rivers pour into it during the rainy season and it appears through them, in any case, since it stops entirely during the season when there is no rain, it is forbidden to immerse in it while it is flowing, until the waters are gathered together. But a river that does not stop, even even if during the rain it swells and and expands over its banks, it is permissible to immerse in it in any case, according to the lenient opinions and the common practice.] (Sefaria translation, emphasis mine.)

So we see that the Rema concludes that it is preferable to follow the Shulchan Aruch’s opinion, but one should not admonish those who do immerse in rivers.

Indeed the [Aruch HaShulchan](https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.201.42?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) notes similar to the Rema that there were those who lived far from proper mikvaos and would thus rely on rivers.

One other area to be conscious of if you are interested in taking a dip in the great outdoors is to be aware of the tznius (modesty) ramifications. [Shulchan Aruch, Yoreh Deah 198:34](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.198.34?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes expressly that one should avoid using such places if one's modesty will be compromised.

Comment: great answer! I would also add that in addition to the concern about צניעות, of paramount importance is physical safety - especially where there are currents or the person is not a strong swimmer. Another factor can also be the potential for חציצה where the bottom of the water is muddy/mucky and may adhere to the skin.